# run python ver 2.5 api from ver 2.7

Tags: python, api, python-2.7

I have to run a python API made for ver 2.5 for automating a specific application. The GUI used to run is already made using ver 2.7. Is there a workaround for me to run the ver 2.5 API using ver 2.7?

Comment: The API should work without modification. If you get any exceptions, post the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You could mess with the module loading search path by:

1. place the 2.5 modules in the current directory
2. edit *PYTHONPATH* environment variable
3. edit `sys.path`

See [Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: This is not at all what the OP intended to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following approaches

1. Try to call the API's first in 2.7 and check whether it works or not.

2. Use below code segment:

```
try: 
import module_only_in_2_7 
except ImportError: 
# provide your own version of that feature
```

3. If you know the API implementation well, visit  [THIS](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27)  page and check if you are using something which is not supported by python 2.7